# Is it possible to query relations from two node which the number of relation greater than a certain value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am a newbie who just started learning graph database and I have a problem querying the relationships between nodes.

My graph is like this:

[image]

There are multiple relationships from one node to another, and the IDs of these relationships are different.

How to find relationships where the number of relationships between two nodes is greater than 2，or is there a problem with the model of this graph?

Just like on the graph, I want to query node **d** and node **a**.

I tried to use the following statement, but the result is incorrect:

```
match (from)-[r:INVITE]->(to)
with from, count(r) as ref
where ref >2
return from
```

It seems to count the number of relations issued by all from, not the relationship between from-->to.

Answer (score 0):

to return nodes who have more then 2 relationship between them you need to check the size of the collected rels.  something like

```
MATCH (x:Person)-[r:INVITE]-(:Party)
WITH x, size(collect(r)) as inviteCount
WHERE inviteCount > 2
RETURN x
```

Answer (score 0):

[Aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) like `COLLECT` and `COUNT` use non-aggregating terms in the same `WITH` (or `RETURN`) clause as "grouping keys".

So, here is one way to get pairs of nodes that have more than 2 `INVITE` relationships (in a specific direction) between them:

```
MATCH (from)-[r:INVITE]->(to)
WITH from, to, COUNT(r) AS ref
WHERE ref > 2
RETURN from, to
```

*NOTE: Ideally (for clarity and efficiency), your nodes would have specific [labels](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/3.5/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-labels) and the `MATCH` pattern would specify those labels.*